# How to get the Thu'um Master achievement?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

The Thu'um Master achievement only says:

*Learn 20 shouts*

I want to know if I need to learn all three words of power for each of the 20 shouts or if the first one is enough? Until now I have learned several words from 19 shouts, but I am far from completing them. If I need all three words of power for each shout I might consider that it is not worth the effort. If I only need to learn one more word of power from an unknown shout, I will definitely go for it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have completed this achievement, it does not matter if you have learned one word or all three as long as you have learned at least the first word from 20 different shouts.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to get one word for each shout to unlock the Thu'um Master achievement. There are twenty shouts in the game.

[Here is a good source about shouts](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_shouts) (with a list of shouts).